# Button with onTouch and onClick

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, ontouch

I have a button for which I am using onTouch so that I can move it around. But the button is now failing to load the contents in onClick. How to make it happen ?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //some code which dosent work
}


@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialX = params.x;
        initialY = params.y;
        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
        return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Voice v1 = new Voice();
            v1.putVoice();
          return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that if we differentiate with ACITON_MOVE position we can get a click event. 
Here is the snippet which did the trick -

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
if(Math.abs(event.getRawX()-initialTouchX )<=2){
floatingFaceBubble.performClick();
return false;
}
```